# Configure Git With Existing Keys

Tags: git

I have configured git with public and private key. I sent my public key to server guy.
Then I formatted my PC and installed windows again. But I saved my both keys on the hard drive before formatting system.
Now I want to reconfigure my Git using existing keys.
How can I do this????

Comment: have you tried simply putting them in the same place they were before?

Comment: are you asking about keys???

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to copy your `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` keys (that you previously saved) in `C:\Users\YourAccount\.ssh` (create the directory '`.ssh`' if it doesn't exist).

That path is what [`git-cmd.bat`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/git-cmd.bat) (in [msysgit](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit)) defines at `%HOME%`, and ssh needs to look for your keys in `%HOME%/.ssh`.
Note that it is important for `HOME` to be defined by a msysgit session (a `cmd` or a [`git-bash`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/share/WinGit/Git%20Bash.vbs)), because Windows itself never defines the environment variable `HOME` (it uses `USERPROFILE` instead, which ssh known nothing about).